# Call the Generic parameterized method in java

Tags: java, generics, graph

What does the error mesaage meant and how to call the generic parameterized method from another class:
Following is the error message:

```
The method add(int, Integer) in the type BinaryMinHeap<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int, Vertex<Integer>)
```

**calling snippet:**

```
 for(Vertex<Integer> vertex : graph.getAllVertex()){
                minHeap.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE, vertex);
            }
```

**method being called is:**

```
  public void add(int weight,T key) {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.weight = weight;
            node.key = key;
            allNodes.add(node);
            int size = allNodes.size();
            int current = size - 1;
            int parentIndex = (current - 1) / 2;
            nodePosition.put(node.key, current);

            while (parentIndex >= 0) {
                Node parentNode = allNodes.get(parentIndex);
                Node currentNode = allNodes.get(current);
                if (parentNode.weight > currentNode.weight) {
                    swap(parentNode,currentNode);
                    updatePositionMap(parentNode.key,currentNode.key,parentIndex,current);
                    current = parentIndex;
                    parentIndex = (parentIndex - 1) / 2;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, the error message says it all: you're passing a `Vertex<Integer>`, but you need to pass an `Integer`.

Comment: How is `minHeap` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you cannot pass a `Vertex<Integer>` into something that only takes `Integer`. If you want to add every element of the `Vertex`, use nested loop. Otherwise you have to map `Vexter<Integer>` to `Integer` somehow.

See method signature:
`BinaryMinHeap<Integer>.add(int, Integer)`

However, you are trying to call it with `Vertex<Integer> vertex` like that: `add(int, Vertex<Integer>)`, which is not applicable (as stated in the error)